# Can somebody explain these specific moments of the musical short cartoon "Coal Black and de Sebben Dwarfs" (1943)?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, jazz, music-video, musicals

**Disclaimer**: Some people probably might find this offensive, and so should not watch it, although I personally don't understand why, and find it to be a very funny and musically catchy cartoon from the golden era of animation:

[Merrie Melodies - Coal Black and de Sebben Dwarfs (1943)](https://archive.org/details/merriemelodiescoalblackanddesebbendwarfs1943)

Having watched it many times over the years, and recently read its [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coal_Black_and_de_Sebben_Dwarfs) article, I've had a number of things/phrases explained which I didn't get myself. However, there are still a few things left which I simply don't understand and cannot look up:

1. At 01:35, a close-up shot of a car tire/tyre is revealed to contain a series of shoes. What is this a reference to? Just a silly reference to the prince being obsessed with jazz/dancing? Or that he's "putting on a fake facade of success"?
2. At 03:10, we see Prince Chawmin' and So White dancing in a silhouette view. So White is kidnapped while the prince falls down as he loses her physical support. However, right after that, it seems like somebody is kicking him from the right part of the screen. It looks really odd. And then, when he stands up again, he appears to be bumping into a metal pole hovering in the air. What's all that about? This is probably the most puzzling part about the entire cartoon.
3. At 03:32, So White says: "Well, thanks for the boogy ride!" What is a "boogy ride"? From the context, my assumption is "the pleasurable ride" or "the joyful ride", but I've never heard that term before and was unable to look it up.
4. At 05:02, So White is singing at the stove: "I's fryin' eggs and porkchops too." Immediately following is the lines (from what I can hear): "Big joins up cause that's good lookin', but the aunt is fast when they says: what's cooking, honey? What's cooking?" I assume that I hear that very wrong, but that's all I can make out. What is she singing for that last part?